# Function does not correctly recognize condition

Tags: python, dataframe

My dataframe (dfd) has a column ('Verleihgruppe') in which numerous articles can be found that were rented. For all records with NaN, products were purchased. Therefore, I try to create a column ('Geschäftsvorgang1') for that assigns the term 'Rental' to all records of that have a value whereas 'Purchase' should be assigned for all NaN.

The problem is that the newly created column only contains the strings 'Rental'. Obviously, it did not recognize the NaN in order to assign these records the right string 'Purchase'.

It would be great if you could help!

Thanks!

```
def product_type(x):
    if x['Verleihgruppe'] == 'NaN':
      return 'Purchase'
    else:
      return 'Rental'
dfd['Geschäftsvorgang1'] = dfd.apply(product_type, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's never good to let `NaN` values in DataFrame so you should replace `NaN` values by 0 thanks to [fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) function and make sure to have numeric data in the `Verleihgruppe` column:

```
import pandas as pd
dfd.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)    
dfd['Geschäftsvorgang1'] = ["Purchase" for r in dfd['Verleihgruppe'] if r == 0 else "Rental"]
```